# I need a help to execute javascript dynamic function function (pageContext) { return (pagecontext["n2"] * pagecontext["n3"] ) } in flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter

```
          public func evaluateJS(functionName : String, argument : [String: Any?]) -> Any? {
    let jsFunc = self.replaceSubContextWithActualValue(key: functionName)
    let jsFunctionVal = "func = " + jsFunc
    let context = JSContext()
    _ =  context?.evaluateScript(jsFunctionVal)
    let jsFunction = context?.objectForKeyedSubscript("func")
    let result = jsFunction?.call(withArguments:[argument])
    return result?.toObject()
}
```

the above code executes like above in ios

Comment: Just what are you doing to "execute" javascript?  There is no DOM in a mobile app.  There's nothing for JS to latch on to.

Comment: Hey I just gave some sample function ,my page context is a dictionary  inside function we have some business logic

Comment: That's even more confusing then.  Why are you talking about JavaScript in relation to a Flutter app?

Comment: I need to hide some fields based on user input data which will get execute by js functions

Comment: Still, there's no Javascript executor in a flutter program.  You're not making sense yet.